# One to one functions and inverse

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, inverse-function

It lists one to one functions:

$g=\{(-5,-3),(2,5),(3,-9),(8,3)\}$

$h(x)= 3x-2$

And it asks to find the following:

$g^{-1} (3) = 
h^{-1}(x)=
(h * h^{-1})(-5)=$

I really need help with this problem, I especially don’t get what g does. Does it multiply all the coordinates by 3? Please help

Comment: It appears that $g$ is simply a set. How do you define the inverse of a set? In all likelihood, what is meant is that the coordinates that are in the set all lie on the graph of $g(x)$. What does it mean for a point to be on the graph of a function? (Think about how you get the graph for a function.)

Comment: @Clayton A function is a set (a subset of the Cartesian product of the domain and codomain satisfying certain properties).

Comment: Hi and welcome to SE. Here's a hint: $g$ is a function that, like any other function, maps values to other values. However, unlike most functions, it doesn't work for all reals. Instead, it only acts on values -5, 2, 3, and 8, and it gives you -3, 5, -9, and 3 respectively.

Comment: @smcc: A function is a rule that assigns elements of one set to another set. A graph is a subset of the product between two sets. As I stated in my first comment, the ordered pairs are likely intended to mean that $g(-5)=-3$, $g(2)=5$, etc. What Todor Markov has written also agrees with this possibility.

Comment: @Clayton A function is usually defined formally as a special type of relation (and a relation is a subset of the Cartesian product of two sets). Formally, a function is its graph.

Answer (score 0):

The inverse of a function is an equation for which f(y)=x. That means, for every point (x,y) on the original function, there is a point (y,x) on the inverse. This means that $g(x)=g^{-1}(y)$, for any (x,y) pair on g(x).  So, the value of $g^{-1}(3)$ is asking for what value of x is y equal to 3, the converse of $g(3)$, which is asking for what value of y is x equal to 3. For sets like g(x), that means looking through and finding pairs in the form (x,3). For equations like h(x), replace the x with y, and the y with x, and isolate the new y in the new equation. That equation is then the equation of the inverse. Then, you can evaluate that equation normally to find various values of $g^{-1}(x)$.